# is it possible to build 2.5 D environment/game in IOS using cocos2D?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Is it possible to build `2.5 D environment/game` in IOS using `cocos2D`?

I am planning to build an app , we can add floor map just like `sims` , edit and drag and drop individual floor tiles , in a 2.5 fashion.

Comment: Possible? Yes. Feasible? Depends. A 2.5D game like Doom/Duke3D is best done with a custom engine. Something like Mario Cart / Lotus Turbo Challenge (Amiga) is quite doable.

Comment: Yes. It is possible. Its just how you code.. =)
Pixel People is an example..